# Phrasal verbs with "on, off, up, etc."

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What do words such as off, up, on used with phrasal verbs mean? What's the logic in that?

Example:
Take: such as bring, get
Off: closed
But if we use together, it mean is flying, or rise.

Not need all phrasal verbs. This was enough. What is the logic in this or what is the point i don't understand? Need to memorize?

Answer (score 3):

Many core English words words (the short ones derived from Norse or German) have multiple meanings... According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take), the word **take** has fifteen meanings as a verb, one of which is

> to move something or someone from one place to another

Similarly, **off** has [multiple meanings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off), one of which is

> away from

So it's not unreasonable for **take off** to mean moving away from the ground. Note that **take off** does not mean "flying, or rise", According to the [Cambridge Dctionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-off), it means

> If an aircraft, bird, or insect takes off, it leaves the ground and begins to fly

So there is a little logic to phrasal verbs... but not much. Phrasal verbs are considered distinct **because** they have a specific meaning beyond the general meaning of their component parts. To quote the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/phrasal-verb) definition:

> a phrase that consists of a verb with a preposition or adverb or both, the meaning of which is different from the meaning of its separate parts

So yes, you do need to memorize them as distinct items. Please refer to a good dictionary to get an accurate definition, and be aware that many phrasal verbs have multiple meanings.

Comment: Thanks. So what should i do? Memorize with meaning or understand logically? If say understand logically, do you suggest any site apart from cambridge dictionary.

Comment: As I said, you need to memorise them as distinct items.